# How can I create a non password user?

Tags: password, users

@work (using Red Hat) we have the notion of npa users, these users are normally for services or applications (git, mysql, nginx etc) and these users can't login themselves. Only as a login authorized user you can `sudo su` to that user, using your own password:

```
sudo su - git
```

which brings me, after specifying my own password, to the git account without the need to specify or store a password for the git account. How can I get the same behaviour in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is a system user what you are looking for? You can create a new one with the following command

```
adduser --system --no-create-home USERNAME
```

This is the kind of account mysql uses. However, you cannot login into these accounts, even with sudo `su - USERNAME`. If you want to be able to login with `su -`, just create a new user without a password.

```
useradd USERNAME
```

He will not be able to login, only with sudo su - USERNAME.